# Android Studio: error: type annotations are not supported

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I've just tried adding an OnClickListener() for a Button in Android Studio but I get the above error suggesting I change to -source 8 or higher.

What is the problem with the below chunk of code?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
  public Button butTest;

//---- THIS BLOCK HERE CAUSES PROBLEM ---->
  public final View.OnClickListener butTest_OnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void onClick( View view )
    {
      //Toast.makeText( this, "Button1 clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
  }
// <<------ END OF PROBLEM

  @Override
  protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
  {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    butTest = (Button) findViewById( R.id.butTest );
    butTest.setOnClickListener( butTest_OnClickListener );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put it inside a method (onCreate for example). You can do as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    butTest = (Button) findViewById( R.id.butTest );

    butTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View view )
        {
            //Toast.makeText( this, "Button1 clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow that worked. I have an app that I wrote ages ago in Eclipse and I'm sure I used to declare the listeners in the class scope rather than within the method scope. Thanks.